# android 4.1 composer->captureScreen(...) failed

Tags: android, screen-capture

I use JNI way, `composer -> captureScreen(...)` to capture final surfaceflinger composed screen, like [this sample](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/android/4.1.1/frameworks/native/services/surfaceflinger/tests/Transaction_test.cpp) in source code.

and build success on android 4.1, but there are error happened at runtime: the `captureScreen(...)` returns `err = 1`, and `heap = null`.

I googled [this link](http://iqwen.net/question/54584) is the same fail, still no answer.

Answer (score 0):

OK! I got the answer...
the `err = 1` means `PERMISSION_DENIED = 1` in native code,
the root cause is after android 4.0 screenshot consider APP's permission , explained [here](http://blog.csdn.net/hk_256/article/details/7306590) in Chinese,
and [here](http://blog.csdn.net/tgww88/article/details/8003117) is the detail to work

thanks!
B.R.